# IE 11 bootstrap dropdown redirecting on click instead of opening it

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Meteor 1.8.1 app that uses Dropdown from Bootstrap 3.3.7. I have the following html on my navbar

```html
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="headerNav">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="/liveView">
          <div class="icon-wrapper">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </div>
          Live&nbsp;View
        </a></li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="/broadcast">
          <div class="icon-wrapper">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </div>
          Broadcast
        </a></li>
      <li><a class="btnSwitchPlace" href="/">
          <div class="icon-wrapper">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="badge">1</span>
          </div>
          <span>Channels</span>
        </a></li>
      <li class="user-menu dropdown">
        <a id="display-name-link" href="#user-menu" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="icon-wrapper">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
          </span>
          {{displayName}}<span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="btnAgencyInfo" href="/agency">Agency</a></li>
          <li><a href="/create">Create Channel</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="/logout">Sign out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

On every browser but IE (tested on IE11) the dropdown opens as expected. On IE, the browser redirects to www.url.com/#user-menu

If I execute from console `$('display-name-link').trigger('click')` the dropdown opens and the bug doesn't trigger.

Comment: Maybe change `href="#user-menu" ` to just `href` and check if this fixes it. Otherwise play around with `event.preventDefault()` or update to Bootstrap 4, which also has div-based dropdowns.

Comment: Well I found 2 workarounds, removing `href` from the HTML or adding a `click` event that just `e.preventDefault()`, but I would like to find out the root cause and fix that instead of adding workarounds, if possible

Answer (score 0):

`{{displayName}}` was causing the component to re-render, since it first returns 'not-logged-in' and then, after the login is performed, it returns the actual name. This somehow causes bootstrap not to reload the events handling the dropdown and the anchor tag executes as it would normally.

Fix was just to add a `e.preventDefault` on the `display-name-link` click event handler.

```
$('#display-name-link').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
})
```